# Converse of the Weierstrass $M$-Test?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was assigned a few problems in my Honors Calculus II class, and one of them was kind of interesting to do:

> Suppose that $f_{n}$ are nonnegative bounded functions on $A$ and let $M_{n} =  \sup f_{n}$. If $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}$ converges uniformly on $A$, does it follow that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_{n}$ converges (a converse to the Weirstrass $M$-test)?

I know that this question has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/question-regarding-weierstrass-m-test), but I'm trying not to just copy an answer off the internet and instead to come up with an example of my own to see if I can actually understand the theorems that I'm learning.

To provide a counterexample, I tried to create a function which has a diverging $\sup$, but I'm not too confident that my proof is valid. Here it goes:

$$
\text Let \ f_{n}(x) = \begin{cases}
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{1 + x}{2}, & \text{if }x \in (-1,0]\\
    \frac{1 - x}{2}, & \text{if }x \in (0,1)\\
    0, & \text{elsewhere}
  \end{cases}, & \text{if }n \text{ even}\\
  \begin{cases}
    x, & \text{if }x \in (0,1]\\
    2 - x, & \text{if }x \in (1,2)\\
    0, & \text{elsewhere}
  \end{cases}, & \text{if }n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, $\text Let f(x) = 0$.

From this definition, I can conclude that
$$
\sup\{f_{n}\} = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if }n \text{ even}\\
  1, & \text{if }n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, to show that ${f_{n}(x)}$ is uniformly convergent, the definition of uniform convergence is used:

$$
\forall_{\epsilon > 0}\ \exists_{N}\ \text s.t.\ \forall_{x}\ \text if\ n > N, |f(x) - f_{n}(x)| < \epsilon
$$

Since $f_{n}(x)$ is strictly nonnegative and $f(x) = 0$, $|f(x) - f_{n}(x)| = f_{n}(x)$. By definition, $\epsilon > 0$, and since $f_{n}(x) = 0$ for $x \geq 2, f(x) - f_{n}(x) = 0 < \epsilon$ for $x \geq 2$. Therefore there exists a $N$ (namely, $N = 1$) which proves that the sequence is uniformly convergent.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n} \neq 0$, by the Limit Test, the infinite sum  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sup{f_{n}}$ diverges, which disproves the converse of the Weierstrass $M$-Test. $\blacksquare$

This is the first time I've actually used LaTeX, so I'm sorry for the way it looks. Is there anything that I can do to make this proof better (or even valid, if it's wrong), or is it fine the way it is?

This might be a bit of a long question...

Comment: Well, it's about time I took a break from SO ;)

Comment: Hmm, why would you do it "the hard way" when it can be done much easier?

Comment: $f_n$ is strictly non-negative seems to be false.

Comment: @Jonas, would you care to elaborate? I would love to know an easier way. @Moron, I think changing $1-x$ to $2-x$ fixes it, right?

Comment: @Blender: I didn't go through the whole thing, but you seem to be going about the wrong way. To prove uniform convergence, you will have to use some test _other_ than the M-Test. After all, you are trying to disprove the converse...

Comment: Thanks @Moron. I looked over the proof after an 1 hour, and I see what you mean. I have the Weierstrass $M$-Test and the definition of uniform convergence completely mixed up, so I think the changes that I made would remove the dependency upon the Weierstrass $M$-Test. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you say that $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\ge 1$? Isn't $f_n(x)=2-x\neq0$ if $n$ is odd and $x\in(1,2)$?

Comment: There are two things that I do not get about your counterexample. (1) The original problem is about convergence of a series of functions, but your example is a sequence, for which the M-test is meaningless. (2) You say that the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to the constant $0$. This is not so: if $-1<x<2$, then $f_n(x)$ does not converge.

Comment: Hmm, that's not very good then. Would defining $f(x) = f_{n}(x)$ fix the convergence problem, as $f(x) - f_{n}(x) = 0$, for all $x$ and $n$?

Comment: @Blender: NO. The limit cannot depend on n! I get the impression that you do not grasp the concept of convergence of a series or sequence of functions.

Comment: Ignore that reference to $n$ (I'm not sure why I even wrote that). I'm beginning to think that my function is unusable for proving the converse false... I'll try and work with what @yoyo posted, but I have no idea what the *chi* with the subscript means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f_n(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $\frac{1}{n}\chi_{(n-1,n)}$.  Then $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly but $\sum_n M_n=\sum_n 1/n$ diverges.  Something like this would work. (Not trying to give an answer away, if this is valid, but trying to show along what lines you should be thinking.)

---

For a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\not\in A$.  Sometimes called the *indicator function* of the set $A$, also denoted by $1_A$.

Comment: If you would like a continuous one you could take triangles instead of indicators.

Comment: Is there an example where the domain is closed and bounded?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal Yes, just smoosh the answer into an interval, e.g. $f_n=\frac{1}{n}\chi_{(1-2^{-n},1-2^{-(n+1)})}$

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer