# Conditions for the Weirstrass M-Test

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a series of functions which converges uniformly and absolutely but does not pass the weirstrass m-test?

Comment: Related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26273/converse-of-the-weierstrass-m-test?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Good question in the sense that we are trained, even in a sleepy or inebriated state to say "*What about the converse*?"  (Not necessarily socially appropriate in all situations but mathematicians are usually oblivious anyway.)

Take the sequence of bounded functions $f_n(x)=1/n$ for $n-1\leq x< n $ and zero otherwise ($n=1,2,3, \dots)$.  On the interval $[0,\infty)$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly.  But  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n\|_\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n =\infty.  $$

[Note added: I see that this does have an answer already somewhere else.  Maybe all questions have been asked before and there is nothing to be asked here except research questions!]

Answer (score 2):

For example, consider 
$$
f_1(x)=x\\
f_n(x)= \frac 1{2^n} \quad n \geq 2
$$
with domain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Not an answer within the spirit of the question however.  Here you have the series $$f_1(x) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n+1}(x)$$ and the latter part does converge uniformly by the M-test.

Comment: No, I think Om is right. This series converges uniformly, and absolutely, on $\mathbb R$ but the first summand is unbounded, hence fails Weirstrass M.

Comment: That's not the point.  Here is a version of the M-test that this example won't work on: *A series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly if there is an integer $N$ so that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty\|f_n\|_\infty<\infty$.*    Who cares what the first 700 terms of the series are doing?  Would you really give up in a situation where the first few terms were unbounded and say "Alas the M-test has failed me!"

Comment: Yes that's true, good point.