# Reciprocal of the Weierstrass $M$ test.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

I need help with this problem:

> Suppose that $f_n$ are continous non-negative fucntions bounded on A
>   and let $M_n=\sup f_n$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly on A, it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges? (a reciprocal of the Weierstrass $M$ test

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you give me some help please?

Comment: I´m not sure but I think its key consider A open or compact

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: My intuition tells me that if A is a compact set then the theorem might be true, but if A is an open set then I think a counterexample might be found. This is only intuition, nothing serious

Comment: See the comment on top answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26273/converse-of-the-weierstrass-m-test for a counterexample.

Comment: But what's the meaning of compact set and open set?